# Intercepting touches in static UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a 5 components UIPickerView which needs to be disabled to normal user interaction (ie: no spinning / clicking around to spin them).  I need however to detect touches inside them and react according to which component was pressed.

I tried UIGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer with cancelsTouchesInView set to YES: It fires up and blocks the single taps but not the dragging around. I tried didSelectRow:inComponent but it's only firing up when the pickers spinned which is a behavior I don't want.. the reels must never spin on a user interaction as mentioned above.

Comment: curious why you want to disable them?

Comment: It's for a slot machine game - I'm using a Spin button to initiate the game and allow respins by clicking on the reels afterwards.

Comment: In that case I would create a custom control since it works so differently from a standard one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a UIGestureRecognizer to the background image (with user interaction enabled) and looking at the locations of the taps to determine if the taps were within the region of a UIPickerView component.